# Error while concatenating the string

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I am trying a make a function that appned a string after another string. I am witnessing the following error. Please help.
*** glibc detected**  ./a.out: realloc(): invalid old size: 0x00007fff7af0d450 **

```
// The following code concatenates the orignal string into the another
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void strcatstring(char *str,char *newstr)
{
    int m=strlen(str);
    int n=strlen(newstr);

    newstr=(char *)realloc(newstr,10*sizeof(char));
    char *newstr1=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    newstr1=newstr;

    while(*newstr!='\0')
    {
        ++newstr;
    }
    while(*str!='\0')
    {
        *newstr=*str;
        ++newstr;
        ++str;
    }

    printf("%s",newstr1);
}


int main()
{
    int n=6;char *str;char str1[10];
    str1[0]='y';
    str1[1]='u';

    str=(char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    printf("\nEnter the string\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    puts(str);
    strcatstring(str,str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first indent your code correctly

Comment: Please view [you indented code and notice](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17569539/revisions) where @Kninnug putted tabs

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to reallocate memory that is not allocated (in the way `realloc` wants it) in the first place.

You declare `str1` as an array in the `main` function, this memory will be allocated on the stack by the compiler and not on the heap. The `realloc` function only can reallocate memory allocated on the heap, either by `malloc`, `calloc` or an earlier `realloc` call.

And if the `realloc` call would have worked, then you have a memory leak, as you allocate memory and assign it to `newstr1` and in the next line overwrite the `newstr1` pointer with the `newstr` pointer.

And you should really not allocate a fixed size, remember that you append one string of size `m` to a string of size `n`. Think about what would happen if `m + n` is larger than 9. Which leads to the next problem, that you don't terminate the resulting string as you don't copy the terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: excellent. You have cleared my one more doubt that regarding why there was no error when I declared str1 using malloc. Thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass pointer to a pointer while calling as follows

```
strcatstring(str,&newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`str1` you are using may not be ending with '\0'. You have to manually put that character at the end.

You can not realloc memory allocated on the stack. `str1` is allocated on the stack.

Proper `strcat()` has the arguments in other order. Destination comes first.

Your naming convention is terrible. `str`? `newstr`? How about `source` and `destination`. Moreover, `m` and `n` say nothing. Why not `sourceLen` and `destinationLen`?

After completing your loop in `strcatstring()` you do not put the '\0' character at the end. You will most probably get memory errors by using that string.

Answer (score 0):

Your str1 is an array, which is allocated on the stack. `realloc()` has to be used on a pointer whose space is allocated on the heap.